# rate_limit() returns wrong reset time

Tags: r, rstudio, rtweet

`rate_limit()` from `rtweet` returns wrong value in column `reset`. Instead of showing 15, it shows values around 14.59. It varies between 14.59 and 14.61. I think it is not a problem with `rtweet` package but probably with either my system or time I have set on my computer.

I can not figure out what might be the reason. The only thing I managed to find out is that when I use `Sys.time` on my computer and some other computer, on which `rate_limit` works fine, there is 25 seconds difference. 25 seconds is around 41% of a minute so it seems that it might be a problem, however I don't know how to solve it. Below SessionInfo:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] pl_PL.UTF-8/pl_PL.UTF-8/pl_PL.UTF-8/C/pl_PL.UTF-8/pl_PL.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bindrcpp_0.2    feather_0.3.1   magrittr_1.5    forcats_0.2.0 stringr_1.2.0   dplyr_0.7.4    
[7] purrr_0.2.4     readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.7.2     tibble_1.3.4    ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.2.1
[13] rtweet_0.6.0   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] reshape2_1.4.3   haven_1.1.0      lattice_0.20-35  colorspace_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.6  base64enc_0.1-3 
[7] yaml_2.1.14      rlang_0.1.4      foreign_0.8-69   glue_1.1.1       bit64_0.9-7      modelr_0.1.1    
[13] readxl_1.0.0     bindr_0.1        plyr_1.8.4       munsell_0.4.3    gtable_0.2.0     cellranger_1.1.0
[19] rvest_0.3.2      evaluate_0.10.1  psych_1.7.8      knitr_1.17       httpuv_1.3.5     parallel_3.4.3  
[25] curl_2.8.1       broom_0.4.2      Rcpp_0.12.13     openssl_0.9.7    scales_0.5.0     backports_1.1.1 
[31] jsonlite_1.5     bit_1.1-12       mnormt_1.5-5     hms_0.3          digest_0.6.12    stringi_1.1.5   
[37] grid_3.4.3       rprojroot_1.2    cli_1.0.0        tools_3.4.3      lazyeval_0.2.0   crayon_1.3.4    
[43] pkgconfig_2.0.1  xml2_1.1.1       lubridate_1.7.2  assertthat_0.2.0 rmarkdown_1.6    httr_1.3.1      
[49] rstudioapi_0.7   R6_2.2.2         nlme_3.1-131     compiler_3.4.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the issue solved itself. I changed timezone (traveled from US back to Europe) and now it works fine.